# How to use a generic expression as class getter

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use a regular expression as generic getter expression of a Class in JS? Works just fine if test is replaced by `"bar"`.

If not, is there an other way to create a generic getter for a class?

```
var test = /^(?!foo).*$/;

var Foo = class {
   get foo() {
      return 'foo!';
   }
   get [test]() {
      return 'the called getter was ' + this.expr;
   }
}

var f = new Foo();

console.log(f.bar)
```

Comment: from documentation I've read it doesn't appear you can do that - I fail to see a valid use case

Comment: @Jaromande well you can use a expression according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: an *expression* isn't a *Regular Expression*

Comment: @JaromandaX I figured that just wanted to know if there was a way to achieve this. Please feel free to answer: 'No its not possible' if its not ;)

Comment: @JaromandaX An example of a valid use case would be to create a custom 2D array class that could be indexed with array[i,j]. Allowing general regexes would be rather extreme, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

[Chapter 12.2.6.8 of ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

It says:

*ComputedPropertyName* : [ *AssignmentExpression* ]

1. Let *exprValue* be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
2. Let *propName* be GetValue(*exprValue*).
3. ReturnIfAbrupt(*propName*).
4. Return ToPropertyKey(*propName*).

So it first calculates the value of the name, then it assign to the property that name

This because a getter method can be only a property name ([14.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions)):

*MethodDefinition* :
**get** *PropertyName* ( ) { FunctionBody }

And a property name can be only a literal property name or a computed property name ([A2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expressions))

*PropertyName*[Yield] :

- *LiteralPropertyName*
- *ComputedPropertyName*